# Pandas increment Dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe, and I would like to increment ' date value' for all of the rows with certain condition as follows:
if the dates are same in the rows, increment the dates by next date, else keep the same date.
the input datafrae

| dates |
| --- |
| 7/24/2023 |
| 7/24/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 |

The expected output as follows:

| dates | new_date |
| --- | --- |
| 7/24/2023 | 7/24/2023 |
| 7/24/2023 | 7/25/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 | 7/23/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 | 7/24/2023 |
| 7/23/2023 | 7/25/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 | 7/17/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 | 7/18/2023 |
| 7/17/2023 | 7/19/2023 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetetimes, create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to `date`s:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['new_date'] = df['dates'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('dates').cumcount(), unit='D')

print (df)
       dates   new_date
0 2023-07-24 2023-07-24
1 2023-07-24 2023-07-25
2 2023-07-23 2023-07-23
3 2023-07-23 2023-07-24
4 2023-07-23 2023-07-25
5 2023-07-17 2023-07-17
6 2023-07-17 2023-07-18
7 2023-07-17 2023-07-19
```

If need original format add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])+pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('dates').cumcount(),unit='D')
df['new_date'] = dates.dt.strftime('%#m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
       dates   new_date
0  7/24/2023  7/24/2023
1  7/24/2023  7/25/2023
2  7/23/2023  7/23/2023
3  7/23/2023  7/24/2023
4  7/23/2023  7/25/2023
5  7/17/2023  7/17/2023
6  7/17/2023  7/18/2023
7  7/17/2023  7/19/2023
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with a daily (`D`) frequency that you will add the the original date:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

df['new_date'] = df['dates'].add(pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('dates').cumcount(), unit='D'))
```

Output:

```
       dates   new_date
0 2023-07-24 2023-07-24
1 2023-07-24 2023-07-25
2 2023-07-23 2023-07-23
3 2023-07-23 2023-07-24
4 2023-07-23 2023-07-25
5 2023-07-17 2023-07-17
6 2023-07-17 2023-07-18
7 2023-07-17 2023-07-19
```